# Структуры данных

Tags: структуры

Какие виды структур данных бывают?(можете указать название структуры в определенном языке программирования) Хочется узнать их предназначение, сильные и слабые стороны. Так же интересует классификация, верно ли в вики написано? [Список структур данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) Развернутый ответ пока каждой структуре не нужен, просто кратко, для примера рассказать в чем преимущество этой структуры перед остальными(например самое быстрое время доступа к элементу, способность динамически менять объем памяти и т.д.)
Может на всё сразу не стоит отвечать, вдруг объем ответа будет значительным, хотя бы по одной из структур которую хорошо знаете можете отписаться, а я буду добавлять в основной пост информацию. Очень удобно будет иметь перед глазами такой список, сразу по нему сверился и выбрал нужное.

**1. Линейные структуры данных** – это структуры данных, в которых переход от одного элемента данных к другому не зависит от каких-либо логических условий, т.е. в линейных структурах используются лишь безусловные связи элементов.

**1.1 Список** Может всё то же самое, что и массив, но позволяет добавлять элементы в любое место, удалять элементы из любого места и получать текущее количество элементов.

**1.2 Ассоциативный массив**

**1.3 Хеш-таблица** - это обычный массив с необычной адресацией, задаваемой хеш-функцией.
Лучший выбор, если не нужна сортировка информации, а только быстрый доступ к ней. Тратится дополнительная память.

преимущества:

- Важное свойство хеш-таблиц состоит в том, что, при некоторых разумных допущениях, все три операции (поиск, вставка, удаление элементов) в среднем выполняются за время O(1), время для наихудшего случая - O(n).

недостатки:

- Итерация не в порядке возрастания ключей
- Необходимость «перехеширования» при увеличении числа хранимых объектов (?)
- нельзя реализовать быстро работающие дополнительные операции MIN, MAX и алгоритм обхода всех хранимых пар в порядке возрастания или убывания ключей (?)
- не поддерживает упорядоченности, и не сохраняет порядок следования элементов (?)
- возможность коллизий

реализация:

- C#: [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)

**1.4 Стек** Набор элементов одного типа, упорядоченных таким образом, чтобы добавлять и доставать элементы можно было только с одного конца. Операции: добавить элемент в стек, достать из стека последний добавленный элемент, проверить, является ли стек пустым.

**1.5 Очередь** Набор элементов одного типа, упорядоченных таким образом, чтобы добавлять их можно было только в один конец, а получать - с другого конца. Операции: добавить элемент в конец очереди, достать первый элемент из очереди, получение размера очереди.

**1.5.1 Очередь с приоритетом**

**1.6 Дек** - особый вид очереди. Дек (от англ. deq - double ended queue,т.е очередь с двумя концами) - это такой последовательный список, в котором как включение, так и исключение элементов может осуществляться с любого из двух концов списка. Частный случай дека - дек с ограниченным входом и дек с ограниченным выходом.

поддерживаемые операции:

- включение элемента справа;
- включение элемента слева;
- исключение элемента справа;
- исключение элемента слева;
- определение размера;
- очистка.

**1.7 Буферное окно**

**2. Граф**

**2.1 Список рёбер**

**2.2 Деревья**

**2.2.1 2-3-дерево**

**2.2.2 Дерево отрезков**

**2.2.3 Красно-чёрное дерево**

**2.2.4 BSP-дерево**

**2.2.5 B-дерево**

Основное предназначение: B-дерево предназначено для хранения информации на жёстком диске. Время произвольного доступа к жёсткому диску очень велико (миллисекунды), поскольку оно определяется скоростью вращения диска и перемещения головок. Поэтому важно уменьшить количество узлов, просматриваемых при каждой операции, то есть высоту дерева, что достигается путём высокой ветвистости.

преимущества:

- Во всех случаях полезное использование пространства вторичной памяти занимает свыше 50 %. С ростом степени полезного использования памяти не происходит снижения качества обслуживания.
- Произвольный доступ к записи реализуется посредством малого количества подопераций (обращения к физическим блокам).
- В среднем достаточно эффективно реализуются операции включения и удаления записей; при этом сохраняется естественный порядок ключей с целью последовательной обработки, а также соответствующий баланс дерева для обеспечения быстрой произвольной выборки.
- Неизменная упорядоченность по ключу обеспечивает возможность эффективной пакетной обработки

недостатки:

- Основной недостаток В-деревьев состоит в отсутствии для них средств выборки данных по вторичному ключу.

**2.2.6 Двоичное дерево поиска**

**2.2.6.1 Самобалансирующееся дерево поиска**

**2.2.6.1.1 АВЛ-дерево**

**2.2.6.1.1.1 Дерево Фибоначчи**

**2.2.6.1.2 Красно-чёрное дерево**

**2.2.6.1.3 Расширяющееся дерево**

**2.2.7 Куча**

**2.2.7.1 Двоичная куча**

**2.2.7.2 Биномиальная куча**

**2.2.7.3 Фибоначчиева куча**

**2.2.7.4 Сливаемая куча**

**2.2.8 Суффиксное дерево**

**2.2.8 Префиксное дерево**

Существует еще следующее разделение структур:

**Статические структуры данных**

**Полустатические структуры данных**

**Динамические структуры данных**

**Нелинейные структуры данных**

[источник](http://khpi-iip.mipk.kharkiv.edu/library/datastr/book/index.html)

**общий вид описания структур:**

-основное предназначение, описание

-поддерживаемые операции

-преимущества

-недостатки

-готовая реализация в языке программирования (название функции или класса)

**условные обозначения**

(?) - под сомнением, поправьте пожалуйста если вдруг неправильно написано или наоборот утвердите чтобы исключить неоднозначность.

редактирование продолжается..

Comment: предлагаю ввести новый пункт в описание структур - это готовая реализация в языке программирования (название функции или класса). Или информация станет трудно читаемой и избыточной? может стоит ограничить список ЯП(языков программирования)? куда входит массив? по вики это подмножество списка, так и есть?

Comment: Впечатляющий обзор. Это уже не обзор абстракций структур данных, что (как мне показалось) подразумевалось в первоначальном варианте. При таком детальном рассмотрении надо учесть одно и двусвязные списки, варианты представления деревьев в памяти (и вообще, по возможности особенности представления структур данных во внутренней и внешней памяти), разрешение коллизий при хэшировании списками и многое другое. Из литературы могу посоветовать первый и третий тома незабвенного Д. Кнута.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, учту. Сама классификация в основном с вики взята. По возможности буду дополнять, времени мало пока.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тема слишком всеобъемлющая для одного ответа, так что была найдена очень полезная статья, предлагаю ознакомиться:

[Обзор наиболее часто используемых структур данных.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128457/)

Answer (score 6):

- Массив. Набор фиксированного количества элементов одного типа, имеющий возможность прочитать или записать элемент по индексу.
- Список. Может всё то же самое, что и массив, но позволяет добавлять элементы в любое место, удалять элементы из любого места и получать текущее количество элементов.
- Множество. Неупорядоченный набор элементов одного типа, каждый из которых может встречаться в множестве не более одного раза. Основные операции над множеством: добавление элемента в множество, удаление элемента из множества, проверка наличия элемента в множестве, получение размера множества.
- Словарь. Неупорядоченный набор элементов двух типов, в котором каждый элемент первого типа связан с одним элементом второго типа, и каждый элемент первого типа (ключ) может встречаться в словаре не более одного раза. Основные операции над словарём: добавление пары "ключ-значение", удаление пары по ключу, проверка наличия ключа в словаре, получение значения по ключу, получение количества пар "ключ-значение".
- Очередь. Набор элементов одного типа, упорядоченных таким образом, чтобы добавлять их можно было только в один конец, а получать - с другого конца. Операции: добавить элемент в конец очереди, достать первый элемент из очереди, получение размера очереди.
- Стек. Набор элементов одного типа, упорядоченных таким образом, чтобы добавлять и доставать элементы можно было только с одного конца. Операции: добавить элемент в стек, достать из стека последний добавленный элемент, проверить, является ли стек пустым.

Comment: Иногда для словаря полезной является еще операция `дай следующую пару`, которая позволяет перебирать все элементы словаря с возможностью их (взятых по этой операции) модификации или удаления.

Comment: Для любых коллекций это полезно.